# Run Java App Locally - How to start appengine-try-java server?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I'm just starting with App Engine, and am trying to get a basic Hello World running locally on my machine to test. I've been trying to follow the tutorial for Java [here](https://console.developers.google.com/start/appengine?_ga=1.40219108.771700088.1424911138).

I get as far as running the following commands:

```
cd appengine-try-java
mvn package
```

At which point the tutorial insists that the server should be built and run and I should be ready to go, except I just get a "build success" and the server isn't running (The terminal output doesn't hang and wait for Ctrl+C, and I can't access localhost:8080).

I've tried figuring out myself how to use the .war file it gives me to run the server using the Apache Maven, but without any luck. I followed the rest of the tutorial exactly. Any advice on what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to run the last command:

> dev_appserver.sh target/appengine-try-java-1.0

with cd you go to the folder, with mvn package you will build the project and with the dev_appserver.sh you will start the actual project.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. The tutorial I was using doesn't include that line, for some reason.